# Прощу оценить код

Tags: laravel

Реализовал простую телефонную книгу так, подправьте, если что не так, как оптимизировать и т.д - https://gitlab.com/phpischka/phonebook

В общем **задача**:

1. Такая добавления контактов у которых может быть много номеров телефонов;
2. Добавления редактирование и удаление `contacts`;
3. Добавления редактирование и удаление `phones`.

Напишите все замечания если есть в ответе, так как хочу писать только качественный код.

Comment: Не стоит писать бизнес-логику в контроллерах. Крайне желательно разбить это на сервисы(в них будет содержаться бизнес-логика) и репозитории(в них пишутся запросы к БД). Схема такова: Контроллер обращается к сервису, а сервис к репозиторию. Также исключения стоит обрабатывать в специальном механизме, сделанным в Laravel. Вот ссылка на документацию https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#the-exception-handler

Comment: спасибо а можете показать пример на одном из методов? это будет всем остальным думаю полезно почитать т.е как вы написали по схеме Контроллер обращается к сервису, а сервис к репозиторию Также исключения стоит обрабатывать в специальном механизме, сделанным в Laravel.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что это запрос код-ревью

Comment: Валидацию можно разместить в Form Request-ах [https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation)

Comment: @ЕгорБанин Репозитории излишни при условии, что Eloquent уже предоставляет всё. Дополнительную логику, связанную с БД можно описывать в моделях. Про сервисы согласен. Исключения обрабатывать через встроенные ларавелевские можно, но специфичные, где нужно что-то дополнительно обработать, иначе это просто лишнее нагромождение; проще пользоваться HttpException из Symphony (да, Laravel имеет много чего от симфони, почему бы этим просто не пользоваться).